# Javascript RegEx number only from number with comma and text after

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this text: `3,142 people`. I need to remove the `people` from it and get only the number, also removing comma(s). I need it to work with any higher numbers too like `13,142` or even `130,142` (at every 3 digits it will get a new comma).

So, in short, I need to get the numeric characters only, without commas and `people`. Ex: `3,142 people` -> `3142`.

My first version that didn't work was:

```
var str2 = "3,142 people";
var patt2 = /\d+/g; 
var result2 = str2.match(patt2);
```

But after I changed `patt2` to `/\d+[,]\d+/g`, it worked.

Comment: Can you show what code you have tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'3,142 people'.replace(/[^\d]/g, ''); // 3142
```

**JSFiddle Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zjx2hn1f/1/**

Explanation

```
[]    // match any character in this set
[^]   // match anything NOT in character set
\d    // match only digit
[^\d] // match any character that is NOT a digit

string.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') // replace any character that is NOT a digit with an empty string, in other words, remove it.
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this:

```
var test = '3,142 people';
test.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
```

It will remove every thing except digit and decimal point